# MySQL - Combining two numbers after a SUM calculation

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my original query that gathers the data I'm trying to combine and turn into a pie chart:

```
select 
`Type of Truck`,
SUM(Profit)
From `table1`
where YEAR(date_of_sale) = 2019 and month(date_of_sale) = 10
GROUP BY YEAR(date_of_sale), month(date_of_sale),`Type of Truck`
ORDER BY `Type of Truck` desc;
```

My result is:

```
Truck Profit
9   47919
8   225
7   -1170
6   293767
5   50634
4   14304
3   30654
21  13484
20  1610
2   288226
19  29134
18  2200
17  575
16  21911
15  1760
14  73476
13  345
12  48680
11  63922
10  29941
1   398265
```

I need to combine Truck 1 and 2 and SUM the result to display into my pie chart.  Right now they're separate.  Also need to combine Truck 4 and 5.

Here is my current query:

```
select *
From


(
select 
`Type of Truck`,
SUM(Profit)
From `table1`
where YEAR(date_of_sale) = 2019 and month(date_of_sale) = 10 AND `Type of Truck` NOT IN(1,2,3,4)
GROUP BY YEAR(date_of_sale), month(date_of_sale),`Type of Truck`
) as a 
,
(
select 
SUM(Profit) as 'FB48'
FROM `table1`
WHERE YEAR(date_of_sale) = 2019 and month(date_of_sale) = 10 AND `Type of Truck` IN(1,2) 

) AS b


;
ORDER BY `Type of Truck` desc
```

The issue is that this query makes a new column and I need it the combined SUMs to be in the same column as Profit so my pie chart will display the numbers correctly.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you explain with an example what exactly are you trying to achieve. take the data set from the first query and post the desired result in your question it will help understanding what needs to be done.
Also in you second query : (select * from (...) a, (...) b ..). you have two columns in a and one column in b which is why result have 3 columns.

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at my answer below, but you may have been on the right track; changing that comma to a UNION could have gotten you closer to the desired results as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want the numbers combined, you can just combine the truck types as single grouping criteria, like this:

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN `Type of Truck` IN (1, 2) THEN '1,2' 
       WHEN `Type of Truck` IN (4, 5) THEN '4,5' 
       ELSE `Type of Truck` 
     END AS ReportingType
   , SUM(Profit)
FROM `table1`
WHERE YEAR(date_of_sale) = 2019 AND MONTH(date_of_sale) = 10
GROUP BY YEAR(date_of_sale), MONTH(date_of_sale),`ReportingType`
ORDER BY `ReportingType` DESC
;
```

Also, note that since your where condition is limiting you considered data to a specific year and month, you do not need to group by year and month.

---

If you want to maintain the simplicity of your original query, or find the above method slows things down (it might interfere with index use), you can also go this route.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN `Type of Truck` IN (1, 2) THEN '1,2' 
       WHEN `Type of Truck` IN (4, 5) THEN '4,5' 
       ELSE `Type of Truck` 
     END AS ReportingType
   , SUM(Profit) AS Profit
FROM (
   SELECT `Type of Truck`, SUM(Profit) AS Profit
   FROM `table1`
   WHERE YEAR(date_of_sale) = 2019 AND MONTH(date_of_sale) = 10
   GROUP BY YEAR(date_of_sale), MONTH(date_of_sale),`Type of Truck`
) AS subQ
GROUP BY `ReportingType`
ORDER BY `ReportingType` DESC
;
```

In this way, the subquery can be a little more direct on taking advantage of indexes, and the combining outer query merely has to sum up the few rows from the original's results.

Comment: Uueerdo: Thanks!  I utilized your top query and it pulled the data perfectly.  Thank you so much for your help!